# Best place to ask about advantages or strengths of a language or framework over another

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where's the best place to ask questions like, "[Advantages of Meteor.js over Angular.js + Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658659/advantages-of-meteor-js-over-angular-js-node-js)"?

People close questions like that as "not constructive" but IMHO the userbase on Stack Overflow is the best userbase to ask!

Comment: Why is it the best place to ask? Because all the users are there. Why are all the users there? Because of not having to answer those versus/battle questions.

Comment: But I find plenty of highly voted "not constructive" questions.

Comment: Popular/upvoted != any lasting usefulness.

Comment: But anyway, where *is* the best place to ask?

Comment: @trusktr - on one of those IRC channels/chatrooms

Comment: @Adel Even some IRC channel banned them, esp Language specific channels. Don't come into #java and say `Lisp is better (because ...)`, but it might be appropiate (if the devs are sometimes in the channel) `I'd like if java has the Bar feature like Lisp`.

Answer (score 11):

There is no place within the network where such a question would be appropriate. The motivation behind this fact has been outlined in a [blog post on the Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: @Bart, thanks for the edit. Much kinder than what I said originally.