# What is the best place to ask an opinion about which CMS is the most appropriate for my task?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want a professional opinion about which CMS is the most suitable to my purpose, I am doubtful about choosing Wordpress or Drupal because I have some specific requests from the client, I wanna summarize them in a question, but which Stack Exchange site is the most appropriate?
I was thinking at Programmers, but what is your opinion?

Comment: That's not really a question for any Stack Exchange site to be honest. Opinion/recommendation is not what we do. Perhaps http://www.slant.co/ would work for you?

Comment: Probably none really. Your question is going to require "discussion" back and forth and "suggestions" which none of the Stacks are for really.

Comment: _"thinking at Programmers"_ -- this is a terrible idea, see [How to Ask](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask), [Help Center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help) and [About](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/about) pages at Programmers

Comment: Well, it seems that not asking directly the real question in Programmers and going here at meta it's been a good idea :D

Comment: "I want a professional opinion" - pay someone. I'm sure CMS consultants exist, you get consultants for everything.

Comment: @AakashM Well, that's not an answer... if you put it this way than the whole Stack Exchange looses meaning: there exist IT consultants, DB administrators ecc ecc, why don't I pay someone for any question I have? Even Google steals work from fooConsultants

Comment: Django CMS is the best. Except when Wordpress is better. Or Drupal too sometimes. Or possibly Joomla.

Comment: @linuxatico: SE doesn't "lose meaning". If you want a "professional opinion", ask a consultant. If you want professional facts, ask an SE site.

Comment: Well written question +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bart has commented you, none of SE network sites likes / allows opinion-based questions.

Here are some corresponding questions on MSO:

- [Best place to ask about advantages or strengths of a language or framework over another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207808/189165)
- [Is there a place to ask opinion based questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201994/189165)
- *too* many more.

I don't know any example of such question, that wasn't immediately closed, so don't even try.